# Prepare on-the-fly flushable image for raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, disk-image

I have a base Raspberry Pi SD image that I flash on all my micro sd cards when I need it.

Depending on the use, I will then have to re-mount the image an change:

- the /boot/config.txt to activate some configuration
- the /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf to setup the appropriate wifi credentials
- another /boot/gui13.conf file that configures what I need the RPi to do.

I have seen that some companies like Balena.io will provide you with a "pre configured image" that already contains the appropriate Wifi credentials (and probably my user id and some kind of credentials to authenticate my rpi to their servers).

See here:
[image: balena ui to prepare an ISO]

How do they do that?

I'd like to do kind of the same thing: being able to insert some JSON / Conf file in my image and prepare a .img file like it.

Do you guys know how they do that? Is there a tool / library to automate this process?

Comment: Do you mean "ISO 9660" the CD format, Or are you asking about a boot image?

Comment: Flashable image, ISO... my age shows..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it would be simpler:

1. Download your RaspberryPi OS image of choice. Say its called `rpios.img`
2. Find the beginning of the `/boot` partition. [Reference](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/13138/92446)

   ```
   fdisk -l rpios.img

   Disk rpios.img: 1.7 GiB, 1858076672 bytes, 3629056 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0x067e19d7

   Device     Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
   rpios.img1        8192  532479  524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
   rpios.img2      532480 3629055 3096576  1.5G 83 Linux
   ```

   Multiply values for **sector size** and **Start** of `rpios.img1` (the `/boot` partition).

   ```
   bc -l <<< 8192*512
   4194304
   ```
3. Mount the `/boot` partition using the offset:

   ```
   mount -o offset=4194304 rpios.img /mnt
   ```
4. Create all files with your desired configs, like `wpa_supplicant.conf` in `/mnt`
5. Unmount `umount /mnt`.
6. Now you have your personalized image which you may flash wherever needed.

   Hint: Using `cp rpios.img /dev/sdb && sync` instead of a `dd`-type command works perfectly well, too, and is simpler, as you do not have to specify block sized for ideal speed.
7. Of course the above steps could be automated (e.g. in a script or else) to create an "individualized" image for each use-case before flashing.